# Update rows with more than one parameter in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have Table in my database table contains three columns ID Images LoginName 
I have this Stored Procedure in my Database

```
alter proc dbo.spGetImages
  @img1 image,
  @img2 image,
  @img3 image,
  @img4 image,
  @img5 image,
  @img6 image,
  @Lname nvarchar(50)
  as begin 

   insert into ImageData (Images, LoginName)
   values
    (@img1, @Lname),
    (@img2, @Lname),
    (@img3, @Lname),
    (@img4, @Lname),
    (@img5, @Lname),
    (@img6, @Lname);

end
```

Now I want to update Images column How can i do that? Basically i want to update images column and Login column I am trying this

```
Create Procedure spChangePassword
   @Login nvarchar(50), @img1 Image, 
   @img2 Image, 
   @img3 Image, 
   @img4 Image,
   @img5 Image, 
   @img6 Image
As
Begin
    Update ImageData Set Images =(@img1,@Login),
   (@img2,@Login),
   (@img3, @Login),
   (@img3,@Login),
   (@img4,@Login),
   (@img5,@Login),
   (@img6, @Login) 
End
```

But query not executing Please help

Comment: `Update ImageData Set Images = img1, LoginName = @Login`

Comment: `update` statements in SQL don't work like that at all. Any introduction to SQL will cover update statements (along with `delete` which has a similar structure).

Comment: FWIW, the image datatype has been deprecated for a little over a decade now. You should instead use varbinary(max). I have to admit it makes absolutely no sense to me that a procedure name spChangePassword receives images as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) documentation for detailed understanding of how and why

```
    Create Procedure spChangePassword
       @Login nvarchar(50), @img1 Image
    As
    Begin
        Update ImageData Set Images =@img1 where Login=@Login
    End
```

Answer (score 0):

In an UPDATE statement, you give each column one value to be used wherever the conditions of the WHERE clause are met.

```
UPDATE ImageData
SET (Images = @image1, Login = @Login)
WHERE (some boolean test here);
```

It seems that you've got the basic syntax of an UPDATE statement wrong. I would suggest reading about them here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp